# Как пользователь может инициировать конкурс с наградой больше, чем его репутация?

Tags: обсуждение

Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645520/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-refresh-google-baner-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B).

Пользователь с 57 баллами репутации предлагает 300 баллов за решение его вопроса. Где он эти 300 баллов возьмет?

Comment: в момент назначения конкурса  у него было 357.... т.е. репа списывается в момент назначения конкурса, а не в момент когда он решил кому-то её присвоить ....... для ознакомления можно почитать справку по конкурсам https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Награда** – это репутация, которая вручается за ответы. Она присуждается
>   из личной репутации пользователя, который начинает конкурс, и **не может**
>   **быть изъята обратно**. Если вы планируете назначить награду за интересующий вас вопрос, на который никто не дал удовлетворительный ответ, учтите, что у вас будут вычтены от *50* до *500* баллов репутации.

Если перейти в профиль пользователя, перейти на вкладку [Репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23033/hitcode?tab=reputation), то там Вы увидите, что у пользователя была репутация до назначения конкурса, ее было больше, чем *57* баллов - а точнее *349* баллов. Затем произошло списание в размере *300* баллов, а затем и другие изменения репутации (голоса  «За» и «Против») Подробнее, про правила конкурсов, их инициацию и привилегии можно прочитать здесь:

- [Что такое конкурс? Как его инициировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)
- [Начинать конкурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)